# Меняются местами dd и MM в DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Есть `ViewModel` с полем `DateTime`:

```
public class GetSalesFilterModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

В контроллере передаю в представление:

```
return View(new GetSalesFilterModel()
{
    StartDate = filter.StartDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Today : filter.StartDate,
    EndDate = filter.EndDate == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1) : filter.EndDate
});
```

При DateTime.Today = 01.12.2016 (1 декабря), в представление передается правильная дата, но при сабмите в контроллер попадает 12.01.2016.

Как это исправить? 
В `ViewModel` задал `DataType`, `DisplayFormat`, но это не работает.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC парсит даты в инвариантной локали если они пришли как GET, и в локали пользователя если они пришли в запросе POST

Answer (score 1):

Просто задайте фиксированный вывод даты.Должно уладить проблему

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy"));

//вывод: 03.13.2017
```

Comment: назовите пожалуйста причину даун воута

Comment: Ну, я не минусил Ваш ответ, но думаю причина простая. Как Ваш ответ относится к вопросу и как он решает проблему в `ASP.NET MVC`? Как автору вопроса поможет вывод в консоль?

Comment: консоль была использована для того чтобы показать аутпут. Я изменил ответ,чтобы дать автору знать что будет лучше задать заранее фиксированный формат даты в форме стринга и затем уже выставлять на вью

Comment: Ну вот и пишите свой ответ так, чтобы было ясно то, что Вы имели в виду. А так, получается, что Ваш ответ просто не несет никакого смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Задавайте формат отображения на самом представлении, а не в модели. Вот так:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}")
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}")
```

Как уже правильно заметил @PavelMayorov: *ASP.NET MVC парсит даты в инвариантной локали если они пришли как GET, и в локали пользователя если они пришли в запросе POST*

Конечно, есть еще вариант с `jQuery DatePickter`, задать внутри него формат отображения даты через `dateFormat`, при условии, что Вы его используете.